# Не создается коллекция с Dictionary<class,int> в FireBase

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-database

Пытаюсь добавить данные, в которых ключ это класс:

```
[FirestoreData]
public class Dish
{
    [FirestoreProperty]
    [Required()]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [FirestoreProperty]
    [StringLength(25)]
    [Required()]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FirestoreProperty]
    public Dictionary<Product,int> ProductsAndCounts { get; set; }
}
```

А значение это число.
В этом же классе тоже есть Dictionary<Class,int>

FireBase на отказ не принимает такие данные, и хочу что бы кто-нибудь дал наводку, как это обойти

Comment: Текст ошибки??? И почему объекты в качестве ключа используете? Это странно, IComparable реализован? Нсли нет, то у вас не только с базой, а и с моделью данных что-то не так.

Comment: Текста ошибки нет, пытаюсь внести, обновляю базу и просто ничего нет. FireBase принимает значения только Dictionary<string, "любое другое">. А смысл тут IComparable? Если вопрос глупый, то простите

Comment: Вы используете словарь, эта коллекция требует уникальных ключей. Как проверяете эту самую уникальность? FireBase видимо тоже в шоке от такого радикального решения (ключом может быть литерал, но не объект). Но я понял, пробуйте другие способы сохранить данные. Советов не даю, потому что без понятия, что вообще происходит, и откуда этот странный словарь взялся. А ошибок не видите видимо потому что не обрабатываете исключения.

Comment: Почему я не могу использовать объект в качестве уникального ключа, если мне это подходит? Мне нужно что бы словарь хранил уникальный объект, а в качестве значения будет число? Все объекты уникальны это 100%

Comment: Можете, словарь вроде не против, как видите. Но в таком формате это уже не словарь, а свалка "ключ-значение", как `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[]`. Суть словаря исчезает ровно в тот момент, когда появляется техническая возможность добавить 2 копии ключа с одинаковым содержимым, а она у вас есть. Отсутствие технического контроля за консистентностью данных ведет к багам и беспорядку. У вас анархическая "лишь бы сдать заказ" разработка или конкретная цель написать качественный проект? Читайте про "внешний ключ" (foreign key), храните продукты отдельно, а ключ из продуктов используйте для этих интов

Comment: Понял, тогда лучше использовать что-нибудь другое. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: насколько я знаю в Firebase данные - максимум json т.е. ключем там точно ничего кроме строки быть не может, все таки это база данных как ни крути